# Разбить массив char (строку)

Tags: массивы, строки, c++

Как разбить **char str[] = "this is a test"** на **out[1] = "this"** и  **out[2] = "is a test"**.

Т.е необходимо взять у строки первое слово отдельно и все что осталось отдельно.

Comment: Все зависит от того, что Вы собираетесь делать с этими данными *дальше.*

В простейшем случае, если Вы уверены, что строка начинается не с пробела, найдите первый пробел и замените его нулем.

Например, что-то в таком духе:

     char *tail = strchr(str, ' ');
     if (tail)
       *tail++ = 0; // теперь tail указывает на "все что осталось".
                    // а в начале str[] осталось первое слово.

Вариантов много. Начните с чтения `man 3 string.h`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если придерживаться темной стороны (Си), то примерно так:

```
char str[] = "This is a string";
char firstWord[30], otherString[30];
int firstWordLen = 0, otherStringLen = 0;

// Ищем пробел и длинну строк
char *space = strstr(str, " ");
firstWordLen = space - str;
otherStringLen = strlen(str) - firstWordLen - 1;

// Копируем первое слово
strncpy(firstWord, &str[0], firstWordLen);
firstWord[firstWordLen] = '\0';

// Копируем остальную строку
strncpy(otherString, &space[1], otherStringLen + 1);
```

Comment: А если уж углубляться в темноту (gcc)


    #define SPACES " \t\n\r\f\v"
    
    void 
    str_word_tail (const char *str)
    {
      int l1, l2;
      char fword[(l1 = strcspn(str, SPACES)) + 1],
        tail[(l2 = strlen(str) - l1) + 1];
      memcpy(fword, str, l1); fword[l1] = 0;
      int gap = strspn(str + l1, SPACES);

      strcpy(tail, str + l1 + gap); 
    
      printf ("fword: '%s' tail: '%s'\n", fword, tail);
    }
    
    ...
    str_word_tail("this  \t\nis a string");
    ...

то так.

    avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
    fword: 'this' tail: 'is a string'

Answer (score 2):

[[@Kenpachi](/users/2807/kenpachi)](/users/2807/kenpachi), думаю для таких задач можно написать не универсальную, конечно, но довольно полезную функцию, которая будет копировать первое слово из строки в буфер в вызывающей программе и возвращать указатель на оставшуюся часть.

(все равно, 7 марта настроение уже не рабочее...).

```
// strword_tail.c
#include <string.h>

#define min(a,b) ({typeof((a)) _a = (a); typeof((b)) _b = (b);  \
                          (_a < _b) ? _a : _b;})
#define SPACES " \t\n\r\f\v"

const char *
strword_tail (const char *str, char *firstword, size_t capacity)
{
  const char *s = str + strspn(str, SPACES),
    *t = s + strcspn(s, SPACES);
  int ll = min(t - s, capacity - 1);

  memcpy(firstword, s, ll);
  firstword[ll] = 0;

  return t + strspn(t, SPACES);
}
```

Ее можно откомпилировать

```
gcc -c strword_tail.c
```

и использовать, например, так

```
// ts.cpp  compile: g++ ts.cpp  strword_tail.o

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" const char *strword_tail (const char *str, char *firstword, size_t capacity);

void
print_words (const char *str, size_t maxlen) {
  cout << "words (max length " << maxlen -1 << " ) of : " << str << '\n';

  char w[maxlen + 1];
  const char *t = str;

  do  {
    t = strword_tail(t, w, sizeof(w));
    cout << '[' << w << "]\n";
  } while(*t);

}

int main () {
  const char *str = "this   \t\nis a string";
  char ss[100] = "This is another string";

  print_words(str, 5);
  print_words(ss, 15);
}
```

в С++.

(Если `strword_tail.c` компилировать `g++ -c strword_tail.c`, то из ее прототипа в `main (ts.cpp)`  надо убрать слова `extern "C"`).

Или практически аналогичная программа как для C (gcc), так и C++ (g++).

```
// ts.c  (if used gcc -c strword_tail.c) compile: 
//       g++ ts.c  strword_tail.o
//   or 
//       gcc ts.c  strword_tail.o
#include <stdio.h>

extern
#ifdef __cplusplus
 "C"
#endif
const char *strword_tail (const char *str, char *firstword, size_t capacity);

void
print_words (const char *str, size_t maxlen)
{
  printf ("words (max length %d) of : %s\n",
          maxlen - 1, str);

  char w[maxlen + 1];
  const char *t = str;

  do  {
    t = strword_tail(t, w, sizeof(w));
    printf ("[%s]\n", w);
  } while(*t);

}

int 
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  const char *str = "this   \t\nis a string";
  char ss[100] = "This is another string";

  print_words(str, 5);
  print_words(ss, 15);

  return 0;
}
```

Вообще, возврат указателя из функции, которая что-то делает со строкой -- это хороший прием.

Answer (score -1):

в php можно например так сделать

```
$data=trim($data);//обрезаем пробелы вначале и вконце
$data=explode(" ", $string);//делим строчку по пробеду
$slovo=$data[0];
unset($data[0]);
$stroka=implode(" ",$data);//соединяем обратно без первого слова
```

C++ не знаю, но там тоже должны быть функции разбиения строки на подстроки.